# Multiplying specific columns of dataframe by constant scalar value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

How do I multiply only specific columns of a dataframe by a constant value?

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : 1.,
                    'B' : 1,
                    'C' : 1,
                    'D' : np.array([1] * 4,dtype='int32')})

mult_by_two = df0.iloc[:,2:].mul(2)
print mult_by_two
```

I get this:

```
   C  D
0  2  2
1  2  2
2  2  2
3  2  2
```

but what I want is this:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  2  2
1  1  1  2  2
2  1  1  2  2
3  1  1  2  2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assign the result to `df0`:

```
>>> df0.iloc[:,2:] = df0.iloc[:,2:].mul(2)
>>> df0

   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  2  2
1  1  1  2  2
2  1  1  2  2
3  1  1  2  2
```

If you want a copy, make before the assigment:

```
df1 = df0.copy()
df1.iloc[:,2:] = df1.iloc[:,2:].mul(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to multiply on scalar you don't need to call `mul` method you could use usual `*` operator:

```
In [24]: df0.iloc[:,2:] * 2
Out[24]: 
   C  D
0  2  2
1  2  2
2  2  2
3  2  2
```

For your question you could use `pd.concat` with your first columns and columns you are multiplying:

```
In [25]: pd.concat([df0.iloc[:,:2], df0.iloc[:,2:] * 2], axis=1)
Out[25]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  2  2
1  1  1  2  2
2  1  1  2  2
3  1  1  2  2
```